# Understanding limit inferior and limit superior using complementary subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

given sequence $(a_n)$ is defined as $a_1=1$ , $a_{n+1}= (-1)^n(\frac{1}{2})(|a_n|+ \frac{2}{|a_n|})$ we had found that $$\lim_{k\to ∞} (a_{2k})= -\sqrt{2}$$ and $$\lim_{k\to ∞} (a_{2k+1}) =\sqrt{2}$$

**From this how can we can conclude that** limit $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = \sqrt{2}$$ and $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n =-\sqrt{2}$$ ?

**I know that limit superior of $(a_n)$ is supremum of set of all subsequential limits of $(a_n)$ and similarly limit inferior of $(a_n)$ is infimum of set of all subsequential limits of $(a_n)$. But here we had just find the two subsequential limits, that is limits of $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$ so from this how we can conclude the value of limit inferior and limit superior?**

Further is there is any easy way to find limit inferior and superior of sequences that are define inductively just like above.

Please help....

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can first narrow down your scope by focusing on $|a_n|$ only, i.e.
$$ |a_{n+1}|= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(|a_n|+ \frac{2}{|a_n|}\right).$$

First note $ |a_{n+1}|= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(|a_n|+ \frac{2}{|a_n|}\right) \ge \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)2\sqrt{|a_n|\times \frac{2}{|a_n|}}=\sqrt{2}.$ Hence $|a_n|\ge\sqrt{2}$ for all $n \ge 2$. Hence $\frac{2}{|a_n|} \le |a_n|$, and $ |a_{n+1}|\le\frac{1}{2}(|a_n| + |a_n|) = |a_n|$.

We now know $|a_n|$ is monotonically decreasing and has an lower bound of $\sqrt{2}$. Hence $|a_n|$ converges. It is a simple calculation to show that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n| = \sqrt{2}. $$

Next $$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \le \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n|=\sqrt{2},$$
and
$$ \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \ge \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(-|a_n|\right) = -\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n|=-\sqrt{2}.$$

Your conclusion is reached since you've already found two converging subsequences.

I think the general way of finding $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ is to find converging subsequences and then bound the general sequence. Others can complement if I miss anything.